# Effects of 2-D Preprocessing on Feature Extraction

Tags: image-processing, preprocessor, sift, surf

Which of this papers is true?

1. " Effects of 2-D Preprocessing on Feature Extraction "

> We show that higher frequencies
>   do not, for the purposes of feature extraction, necessarily represent
>   human-salient features and that the combination of contrast
>   enhancement, decimation, and lowpass filtering achieve more
>   robust feature extraction than simple high-frequency boosting.
>   Our ideal feature extractor therefore incorporates a decimator for
>   reduction to an idealized size, contrast enhancement through
>   stretched dynamic range, and frequency-domain filtering with a
>   Gaussian lowpass filter."

2. " Fast SIFT algorithm based on Sobel edge detector "

> This paper proposes a fast SIFT
>   algorithm based on Sobel edge detector. Sobel edge detector is
>   applied to generate an edge group scale space and SIFT detector
>   detects the extreme point under the constraint of the edge group
>   scale space. The experimental results show that the proposed
>   algorithm decreases the redundancy of keypoints and speeds up
>   the implementation while the matching rate between different
>   images maintains at a high level. As the threshold of Sobel
>   detector increases, number of keypoints decreases and matching
>   rate gets higher.

Comment: They're both true? They wouldn't be published papers if they weren't.

Comment: These two parts don't seem to be in contradiction.

Comment: @FiReTiTi thank for answered my problem is that paper one say that the high frequency dose not important but second use edge for improve sift algorithm

Comment: @rayryeng thank for answered my problem is that paper one say that the high frequency dose not important but second use edge for improve sift algorithm –

Comment: Caution, they are talking about two specific problems. If you make tests with the cooccurrences matrix + Haralick, you will see that sometimes do not reduce the number of gray level (so do not reduce the number of frequencies) improves the classification result.

Comment: @FiReTiTi thanks but can you explain more.

Comment: SIFT uses Canny filter principle to extract characteristic points. It does that for all frequencies. So compute a Sobel gradient before SIFT, guides it on using specific parts of the image (low/high frequencies do not matter). So for the second paper, they are talking about characteristic points extraction (even if it is not explicit), when in the first paper they are talking about features extraction. So two specific and different problems

Comment: @FiReTiTi in summarize if i extract edge then use sift improve it?or save hard space(if data is big) or trade-off?

Comment: I haven't read the paper, and I am not a SIFT user. It may improve the results, but no clues. But saving space no, because you still have to manipulate the same images, except if you make a threshold on the gradient result.